# Ą is not the same size as T

Tags: html, css

The Ą is not the same size as T. Anyone know how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Use a font in which all the characters "look right".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a font which includes all the characters you want so the system doesn't have to substitute a different one when it hits a character which isn't in the current font.

Comment: Ahhh, this explains it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/list/language/polish

This list filter all fonts which render well polish characters, donwload one and your characters will all be the same height :).